# strip two named querystring params from url using regex and replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a url like:

```
http://example.org/someparam=asdfadfsadf&lmnop=Lasda:sdf&radParam=dfadfs&qrstu=asfasdf:asaasd
```

I have this regex:

```
/(&|\?)(lmnop|qrstu)=.*?(&|$)/
```

But I want to match both not just the first?

The desired result is the url with the two querystring params and their values removed:

http://example.org/someparam=asdfadfsadf&radParam=dfadfs

Comment: Did you try using the global flag `/g`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird no, not sure where it would go?

Comment: @Mandy8055 the regex you suggested only matches the first? thanks!

Comment: If you want to replace the groups with different values, you might check for the value of each group. See  https://ideone.com/cT45xR

Comment: @Mandy8055 You already have given a good answer, feel free to add or adjust it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st approach without using regex:**

**Proposed Idea:**

```
1. Split the string on & symbol.
2. Filter out those elements of the split string in step 1 which starts with lmnop= or qrstu=.
3. Join again on & symbol.
```

Please find the sample implementation below:

```js
let string = `http://example.org/someparam=asdfadfsadf&lmnop=Lasda:sdf&radParam=dfadfs&qrstu=asfasdf:asaasd`;
console.log(
// Step 1
string.split("&").
// Step 2
filter(el => !(el.startsWith("lmnop=") || el.startsWith("qrstu="))).
// Step 3
join("&")
);
```

---

**2nd Approach Using regex:**

You may try:

```
&(?:lmnop|qrstu)=(.*?)(?=&|$)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`&`** - Matches `&` literally.
- **`(?:lmnop|qrstu)`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching `lmnop` or `qrstu`.
- **`=`** - Matches `=` literally.
- **`(.*?)`** - **Lazily** matches everything till the end or `&`.
- **`(?=&|$)`** - Represents a positive look-ahead which asserts end or `&`.

---

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/VD4i2T/2)

[image: Pictorial Representation]

```js
const regex = /&(?:lmnop|qrstu)=(.*?)(?=&|$)/gm;
const str = `http://example.org/someparam=asdfadfsadf&lmnop=Lasda:sdf&radParam=dfadfs&qrstu=asfasdf:asaasd`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The first solution does work but how can I get the remaining string rather than the extracted querystrings? The regex matches the first but not both.

Comment: Yes I want to remove those two querystrings and their values while leaving the rest of the url intact.. no extra & etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to @Thefourthbird for suggesting a beautiful enhancement in the mentioned regex.